# Python/Pyomo with glpk Solver - Error

Tags: python, pyomo

I am trying to run some simle example with Pyomo + glpk Solver (Anaconda2 64bit Spyder):

```
from pyomo.environ import *
model = ConcreteModel()
model.x_1 = Var(within=NonNegativeReals)
model.x_2 = Var(within=NonNegativeReals)
model.obj = Objective(expr=model.x_1 + 2*model.x_2)
model.con1 = Constraint(expr=3*model.x_1 + 4*model.x_2 >= 1)
model.con2 = Constraint(expr=2*model.x_1 + 5*model.x_2 >= 2)

opt = SolverFactory("glpk")
instance = model.create()
#results = opt.solve(instance)
#results.write()
```

But i get the following error message:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'c'
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-e074641da66d>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/..../Exampe.py', wdir='D:.../exercises/pyomo')

  File "C:\...\Continuum\Anaconda21\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\....\Continuum\Anaconda21\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 74, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "D:/...pyomo/Exampe.py", line 34, in <module>
    results = opt.solve(instance)

  File "C:\....\Continuum\Anaconda21\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py", line 580, in solve
    result = self._postsolve()

  File "C:\...Continuum\Anaconda21\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\solver\shellcmd.py", line 267, in _postsolve
    results = self.process_output(self._rc)

  File "C:\...\Continuum\Anaconda21\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\solver\shellcmd.py", line 329, in process_output
    self.process_soln_file(results)

  File "C:\....\Continuum\Anaconda21\lib\site-packages\pyomo\solvers\plugins\solvers\GLPK.py", line 454, in process_soln_file
    raise ValueError(msg)

ValueError: Error parsing solution data file, line 1
```

I downloaded glpk from http://winglpk.sourceforge.net/ --> unziped + added parth to the environmental variable "path".

Hope someone can help me - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem with GLPK 4.60 (glpsol changed the format of their output which broke Pyomo 4.3's parser).  You can either download an older release of GLPK, or upgrade Pyomo to 4.4.1 (which contains an updated parser).